# Lutron occupancy sensor MS-OPS2H - Ground issue (I think)

Tags: switch, ground

Trying to install occupancy sensor to turn on low voltage stair lights. Power comes into metal gang box. Ground goes to ground bundle, with pigtail to the box.  White goes to neutal bundle. Black is connected to the white traveling to the switch, as in switch loop.

I have a transformer in the box with a black/ white/ green. Green goes to ground bundle, white goes to the neutral bundle, black goes to the switch.

At the switch box (plastic), one black wire is connected to the black wire (coming from transformer). The other black is connected to white (black tape) as in a switch loop. Green and bare are connected to ground.

Power on and power is traveling to the switch, but it's not turning on or sending power to the transformer. I have to assume there is a ground issue. But I'm not sure what else to try.  **The real stick in my mud is that I ran a test of this mockup (no boxes) and it all worked. The sensor turned on and turned on my low voltage light via the transformer.**

Power is coming from a circuit where everything else is working/functioning as normal (another light switch loop and outlet with doorbell transformerall works).

Any ideas?

Comment: Ground is not part of the power circuit.  It is there to provide a safe path for shorts to trip breakers, so it should not matter if it is there or not.  Probably there is a problem with connecting the live and neutral wires.  Pictures of the problem box will help.

Comment: One quick test for ground is to use a multi-meter/voltage meter and test the voltage between live/hot and ground.  The reading should be ~120 volts for a good ground connection back to the panel.  The same reading should be gotten between live and neutral, and 0 volts between neutral and ground.

Comment: Tell us more about the transformer

Comment: Did you hook up the motion sensor backwards? Does the motion sensor require a neutral?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try the multimeter reading. The only neutrals are the power line and the transformer and they're connected.  Not sure what else to say about the transformer. Basic one that runs low voltage doorbells. It takes the 120v and drops to like 18 or something.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica In a quick look I didn't see a line vs. load configuration on the switch. But it is definitely "ground required, neutral not used".

Comment: Not sure how to install it backwards. The 2 blacks on the switch are to be hooked up to 2 blacks coming from a box,  or if you don't have 2 blacks,  1 black and 1 white (switch loop). Shouldn't matter which switch wire is connected to which box wire. No neutral so the 2 ground go together to the ground from the source.

Comment: Thanks,  manass.... yes, definitely. Ground are connected,  no neutral.

Comment: If it doesn't care which side is supply vs lamp, and it doesn't have neutral, then *how does it power its own internals?* That's the question to ask.  The green *and* bare wire is a hint.  Is the ground at the switch a good valid ground?

Comment: what happens if you just hock up a light bulb instead of transformer

Comment: Ruskes - Will be trying tonight.

Comment: Just wondering if the inrush current to the transformer exceeds the sensor capability

Comment: @JeffM. why are you wiring this sensor as ground-required/no-neutral? Simply slip the green sleeve off the "green" wire and connect it to neutral instead of ground.

Comment: UPDATE: so you guys are gonna love this.  Went to bed without running any further tests, woke up and the lights were on. Meaning the power was going through the motion sensor,  back down to the transformer and powering the lights. However, the switch does not turn the lights off, nor allows me up update the settings. I ran a test using another incandescent lamp, still using the sensor and same thing. Powered up, switch doesn't turn off.

Comment: Multimeter tells me I have 120V hot-neutral, but only 9V hot-ground. I'm still at a loss as to why it would work in my mock-up but not installed with everything in exactly same place.

Comment: @Threephase, because there is no neutral coming into the switch box.  The "white" is actually hot coming from power and the black is sending power back to the lights. It's a switch loop.

Comment: @JeffM. -- ah.  thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1):

Based on "mockup worked, no boxes", it sounds like the problem is indeed the ground, as this switch can't work without ground as it uses ground for a current return path instead of neutral.

But first, I would rule out any transformer issue. Connect a receptacle in place of the transformer. If that works then there is an issue with the transformer. If that doesn't work then the issue is the wiring or the switch.

As noted in comments, use a multimeter to check if you have a good ground or not. You should get 0V (continuity actually) between ground and neutral (where neutral is available) and ~ 120V between ground and hot and between neutral and hot. If you have those values correct then I would swap the fancy switch for a simple toggle switch and see if that works, as it would not be dependent on ground or neutral.

A couple of other things to consider:

- Use a metal box for the switch. You already have a metal box for the transformer, so why not for the switch? Can't say for sure with this particular switch, but in general switches can get ground via metal yoke to metal box. And other advantages too.
- If this is a new switch then in theory there should be neutral - i.e., run a 3-wire cable (black hot, white neutral, red switched hot) instead of a switch loop. Once you do that, your possible switches expands to include "neutral required" switches.